# Invalid:error connecting to backend after clicking on API publisher test button

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I Configured WSO2 Api Manager product on unix environment.I am able to login carbon,publisher and store url by using DNS name of server.By using below url I am able access carbon, publisher page::

**https://abc.xx:9445/carbon**

For testing purpose I deployed sample application in publisher.
Url I am try to hit from publisher API::
**https://abc.xx:9445/am/sample/pizzashack/v1/api**

But After clicking on test button(i.e. production endpoint) by using DNS name of server it gives me **Invalid:error connecting to backend**.Checked log it shows connection timeout for **https://abc.xx:9445/am/sample/pizzashack/v1/api**url.

If I use IP instead of DNS name it gives me **bad certificate** error in log.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: What is the behavior if you publish the api and invoke ?

Comment: What is mean my behavior here?

Comment: are you able to access the api by publishing it to gateway ?did you try that ?

Comment: I published api successfully using publisher and also I can see the all requestmapping in Subscribers also.But when i tried to test any service it gives me error.Also I trired with curl command.

Comment: if you are facing the issue once published to the gateway and invoking it , you can trouble shoot the issue by enabling wirelog in gateway, 
http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: Please see this: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5844

Comment: Did you find the solution?